# calculate variance in effect coding

Tags: r, variance, confidence-interval

I want to calculate standard error or more accuratly a Confidence-interval for
an effect coded variable. Here's a minimal example:

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars$gearEff <- C(factor(mtcars$gear), sum, 3)
contrasts(mtcars$gearEff)
  [,1] [,2]
3    1    0
4    0    1
5   -1   -1
mod1 <- lm(mpg ~ gearEff, data=mtcars)
summary(mod1)

##..truncated output...
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  20.6733     0.9284  22.267  < 2e-16 ***
gearEff1     -4.5667     1.1639  -3.924 0.000492 ***
gearEff2      3.8600     1.2156   3.175 0.003534 ** 
###...
```

I now am able to calculate the gearEff3 effect via:

```
-coef(mod1)["gearEff1"] - coef(mod1)["gearEff2"]
0.7066667
```

Does anyone know how to compute a confidence interval or the standard deviation
for the gearEff3? My final goal is to plot a Foresplot with these data, but I am 
not able to calculate this confidence interval. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: not sure, but perhaps `mod1.noint <- lm(mpg ~ gearEff-1, data=mtcars)` would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the standard errors of the differences among factor levels in a linear model using the "aov" function from the `stats` package. These can then easily be extracted for graphing:

```
# graphing differences among factor levels (with standard errors)
# require(stats)
m <- lm(mpg ~ gear, data=mtcars)  
plot(TukeyHSD(aov(m))) # ?aov
```

[image: Mean Differences in Levels]

However a more informative approach for graphing would be to plot the conditional mean outcome for each factor level with their standard errors. Not only is this easier to interpret for the reader, but it accords with the principle that statistical graphics should convey as much information as possible in a parsimonious fashion:

```
# require(effects)
plot(allEffects(m))
```

[image: Mean MPG by Gear Level]

Comment: Thanks. I was doing this for a mixed model of class `lme4:::glmerMod`. `allEffects` exists also for this class and the resulting object `allEffects(m)` is a list with everything I need. I assume standard Wald-CI's are calculated?

Comment: I looked through the documentation and I couldn't find a reference to how the standard errors are calculated, but without any mention I'd assume they're based the standard Wald confidence intervals.

Comment: ... which, if true, means there would not be any correction for multiple corrections. (and isn't `TukeyHSD(aov(...))` exactly what I suggested?)

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly clear what you want since there is no gearEff3. `gearEff1` appears to be 3-5 comparison and gearEff2 is the 4-5 comparison. (I don't think your calculation of `gearEff3` makes any sense.) It appears you want to examine a single cross-factor comparison and that it might be the 4 versus 3 gear comparison? You can use the TukeyHSD function to generate comparisons and confidence intervals that are adjusted for the multiple comparisons issue (that you may not have recognized.)

```
TukeyHSD(aov(mod1))
#----------
  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level

Fit: aov(formula = mod1)

$gearEff
         diff        lwr       upr     p adj
4-3  8.426667  3.9234704 12.929863 0.0002088
5-3  5.273333 -0.7309284 11.277595 0.0937176
5-4 -3.153333 -9.3423846  3.035718 0.4295874
```

Notice that the contrast definitons does not reallya ffect this output:

```
mod2 <- lm(mpg ~ factor(gear), data=mtcars)  # standard R treatment contrasts by default
TukeyHSD(aov(mod2))
 #--------------------------
  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level

Fit: aov(formula = mod2)

$`factor(gear)`
         diff        lwr       upr     p adj
4-3  8.426667  3.9234704 12.929863 0.0002088
5-3  5.273333 -0.7309284 11.277595 0.0937176
5-4 -3.153333 -9.3423846  3.035718 0.4295874
```